# Order a data set with serial marks

Tags: python

I have the following data set:

```
import random

def get_data():
    data = []
    for a in xrange(10):
        serial_id = random.randint(0, 100)
        node_data = 'data-%d' % (a)
        data.append((serial_id, node_data))
    return data
```

Which gives (well, it is random, so ymmv):

```
[(58, 'data-0'), (37, 'data-1'), (68, 'data-2'), (80, 'data-3'), (89, 'data-4'), (42, 'data-5'), (2, 'data-6'), (90, 'data-7'), (53, 'data-8'), (7, 'data-9')]
```

I would like to order this data set by `serial_id`, implementing:

```
def order_data(data):
    ...
    return ordered
```

Where ordered would be:

```
[(2, 'data-6'), ... , (90, 'data-7')]
```

What would be the most pythonic/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sorted`:

```
return sorted(data)
```

or, if you don't care about modifying `data`, you can just use `.sort` to do a (slightly more efficient) in-place sort:

```
data.sort()
return data
```

The comparison function for tuples orders them by their first element, then their second element, and so on.

Comment: To explain: the default sort for tuples is to compare each element of the tuples in order. in this case the default sort wil sort on the first element of the tuples, which is the `serial_id`. If the `serial_id`s are equal then it'll compare on the `node_data`.

Comment: I see. What if the instances of `node_data` are not comparable?

Comment: Then you can use `.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])` (or `key=operator.itemgetter(0)`) to sort only on the first element.